# How to remove a git repository from the Repository Browser on Netbeans?

Tags: git, netbeans, repository

I can still see my Git Repository when I click on :

```
Team > Git > Repository Browser
```

Even though I have deleted the .git folder from the files of the Project.

I have tried to disconnect / reconnect, still the same.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Found the solution, just have to restart Netbeans...

Answer (score 0):

I used Netbeans 12.4. I can reset by right click the project name. It will show pull down menu. Select Git->Revert/Recover>Reset...
It will show the reset screen. click "Select" to select the version you want to reset !!!